# Compute the Matrix Representation of a Map from $\mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{P}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ denote the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ in one indeterminate over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\{1, x, x^2, \cdots, x^n\}$. Consider the mapping $L: \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^3$ defined as follows:
$$L: p(x) \mapsto \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}p(x) + \int_{0}^{x}p(\xi)\text{d}\xi, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, p(x) \in \mathbb{P}^2$$

Let the subspace $W \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be defined as $W = \text{span}\{1 - x^3, x +x^2\}$ and consider the subspace $L^{-1}W \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ defined as follows:
$$L^{-1}W = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{P}^2: \,\, Lp(x) \in W\}$$
Compute the matrix representation of the insertion map $V: L^{-1}W \to \mathbb{P}^2$ of the subspace $L^{-1}W$ in the given basis for $\mathbb{P}^2$

**Starting Out**:

I want to find the subspace in $\mathbb{P}^2$ that shows the following relationship in $\mathbb{P}^3$ as determined by the linear operator $L$:

$$p(x) \in W \,\,\text{such that}\,\, p(x) = \alpha_1(1 - x^3) + \alpha_2(x + x^2)$$
or
$$p(x) = -\alpha_1x^3 + \alpha_2x^2 + \alpha_2x + \alpha_1 \in \mathbb{P}^3$$
where $\alpha_2$ is the coefficient of $x^2$, $x$

and $\alpha_1$ is the coefficient of $c$ (constant) and $-\alpha_1$ of $x^3$

Normally, I would set up a relationship between different bases and compare coefficients to create a matrix.

Since $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and not the entire *ambient* space would there only be two such relationships?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, find out the vector space $L^{-1}W$.

Let $p\in P^2$ with $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$.
Note that by definition $p \in L^{-1}W \iff Lp \in W$.

Compute $Lp$
\begin{align}
  Lp(x) &= p'(x)+\int_0^x p(t) \, dt
  \\
  &= (b+2cx) + (ax+\frac{b}{2}x^2+\frac{c}{3}x^3)
  \\
  &= b + (2c+a)x + \frac{b}{2}x^2 + \frac{c}{3}x^3
  \\
  &\overset{!}{=} \alpha (1-x^3)+\beta(x+x^2)
  = q(x)
\end{align}
where $q\in W$.

By comparing coefficients we get $b=\frac{2}{13}a, c=-\frac{6}{13}a$ which yields the subspace as
$$
L^{-1} W = \text{span}\left\lbrace1+\frac{2}{13}x-\frac{6}{13}x^2 \right\rbrace \,.
$$

A matrix representation for $V$ depends on the basis you choose for $L^{-1}W$
whereas we use the monomial basis $(1,x,x^2)$ for $P^2$.

Using the obvious basis $1+\frac{2}{13}x-\frac{6}{13}x^2$ yields the matrix
\begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    \frac{2}{13} \\
    -\frac{6}{13}
  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1} \,.
\end{align}